# Why I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError is not defined error in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError is not defined" error when I am going to call the `updateinventory()` function from the appended update button. I don't know what is the problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("i").click(function() {

  var id = this.id;
  var product_code =   $('#pr_code'+id).val();
  var user_id =   $('#user_id'+id).val();
  var qty = $('#qtyspan_'+id).text();

  $('#qtyspan_'+id).css('display', 'none');
  $('#'+id).css('display', 'none');

  $('#simplyupdate'+id).append('<div id="updateinventorydiv'+id+'" class="input-group" style="width: 227px;"><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden"  id="pr_coding" value="'+id+'"/><input value="'+qty+'" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></div><span class="input-group-btn"><button onclick="updateinventory('+product_code+','+user_id+','+id+')" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button">Update</button><button id="canceldiv_'+id+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">cancel</button></span></div>');
});

function updateinventory(product_code,user_id,outlet_id) {
  alert(product_code);
}
</script>
```

PHP file: This is the PHP code where I have created 3 hidden inputs to get the ids in JavaScript.

```
for ($t = 0; $t < count($outletData); ++$t) {
  $outlet_id = $outletData[$t]->id;
  $outlet_name = $outletData[$t]->name;
  ?>

  <div class="row" style="padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <?php echo $outlet_name; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9" id="simplyupdate<?php echo $t; ?>">

      <?php
      $invQty = 0;
      $invQtyData = $this->Constant_model->getDataTwoColumn('inventory', 'product_code', $code, 'outlet_id', $outlet_id);
      if (count($invQtyData) > 0) {
        $invQty = $invQtyData[0]->qty;
      }
      ?>

      <span id="qtyspan_<?php echo $t; ?>"><?php echo $invQty; ?></span>
      <input type="hidden"  id="pr_code<?php echo $t; ?>" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden"  id="user_id<?php echo $t; ?>" value="<?php echo $user_role; ?>" />
      <input type="hidden"  id="outlet_id<?php echo $t; ?>" value="<?php echo $outlet_id; ?>" />
      <i class="fa fa-pencil" id="<?php echo $t; ?>"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The way you have your append written, your arguments to updateInventory won't be quoted and will be interpreted as variables instead of strings.

Comment: What should i do?

Comment: Quote them?....

Comment: can you please suggest as i think i am doing it right...

Comment: @Devon i am getting this error "editproduct?id=3:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: UD0003 is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (editproduct?id=3:1)"

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the `updateinventory` arguments not beeing quoted.

It should be:

```
<button onclick="updateinventory(\''+product_code+'\',\''+user_id+'\',\''+id+'\')" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="button">Update</button>
```

Notice the backslashes `\` to escape them... Pretty complicated. **So beyond that**, here is a better way to achieve the same. You use jQuery... So do not use the inline `onclick=...`.

Give your button a class... Say `update`. Then use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on it, since it is appended (dynamically created).

About the `product_code`, `user_id` and `id`, first store it in some [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and on button click, retreive the values using [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

I made the changes below... Untested ;) Try it.

```
$("i").click(function() {

  var id = this.id;
  var product_code =   $('#pr_code'+id).val();
  var user_id =   $('#user_id'+id).val();
  var qty = $('#qtyspan_'+id).text();

  $('#qtyspan_'+id).css('display', 'none');
  $('#'+id).css('display', 'none');

  $('#simplyupdate'+id).append('<div id="updateinventorydiv'+id+'" class="input-group" style="width: 227px;"><div class="form-group"><input type="hidden"  id="pr_coding" value="'+id+'"/><input value="'+qty+'" type="text" class="form-control input-sm"></div><span class="input-group-btn"><button data-productcode="'+product_code+'" data-userid="'+user_id+'" data-id="'+id+'" class="btn btn-success btn-sm update" type="button">Update</button><button id="canceldiv_'+id+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button">cancel</button></span></div>');
});

$(document).on("click",".update",function(){
  var product_code = $(this).data("productcode");
  console.log(product_code);
});
```